# Should I use polymorphism to model these relationships?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, data-modeling

I'm working on an app with **Project**, **User**, and **Group** models. A Project has many groups, a User belongs to many groups through a **Membership** model. I have two choices:

1. When a Project is created, a default group is created. Any person participating in this project is automatically added to it.
2. Make Memberships polymorphic so that users can be a member of a project, and a group in the project.

Both approaches have wider implications: Other models will come into play, such as: File, Post, and Task.

If I go for option 2, those models will also have to be polymorphic. But it would simplify things a bit.

If I go for option two, I forgo polymorphism, but things get a bit complicated. For example, finding the users projects means I have to query for the user's groups, then projects associated with those groups, and then make sure the projects are unique.

Has anyone faced a similar situation, any advice or additional pros and cons for either approach?

I really would rather ditch groups altogether, but it's a requirement for permissions, to separate content based on group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think best option would be creating a default group, because:

1. Then you can go with a clear structure:

   - projects - has many groups
   - groups -> has many users etc,
2. you will have the flexibility of managing groups easily
3. your core structure is simple, hence years down the line, easy to expand
4. you are easing the work flow of user by automating a one step. I personally believe if you could let a user to up and running quickly, they will find your system user friendly